# StackOverFlowError at Runtime

Tags: java

When I run this code I am getting a `StackOverFlowError` at runtime. Why am I getting this Exception?

```
 class F{
    String name;
    int rollNo;
    F ref;

    F(String name,int rollNo){
        this.name = name;
        this.rollNo = rollNo;
        ref = this;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        F f = new F("Shivam",138);
        System.out.println(f);
    }

    public String toString(){
        return name+" "+rollNo+" "+ref;
    }
}
```

This is the Exception I am getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:449)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:136)
    at F.toString(F.java:20)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at F.toString(F.java:20)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at F.toString(F.java:20)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
```

Comment: What did you expect the program to print?

Comment: Problem is with the inclusion of "ref" in the toString(). By including the "ref" there, it tries to evaluate ref.toString within the toString() method itself. Better if you can share what is your intended output of toString.

Comment: It is just a matter of endless recursion.

Comment: System.out.println(f); is the Problem Recheck.

Comment: I want to print the value of instance variables as well as the objects reference code.

Comment: It makes no sense to keep a reference to the object itself in a field. You can reference the object itself via `this` from anywhere inside the instance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
System.out.println(f); // cause StackOverFlow  Exception
```

when  this line executes  `toString()` method called of `f` object. and 
see the implementation of `toString()`

```
public String toString(){
    return name+" "+rollNo+" "+ref;
}
```

In which you again concatenate  the `ref` object so, `toString` method recursively calling infinitely.
change implementation of `toString` to this.

```
public String toString(){
    return name+" "+rollNo;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are self referencing using `ref` and printing in `toString()` which creates an endless recursion of `toString()` being called. Not sure why you need a self reference in the first place, you can just use `this` when needed. if you really need `ref`, you can remove it from `toString()` method and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Problem with overridden method *toString()* when you use *ref* it calling its *toString()* method and again same method call became recursive which causes the problem.
You should use field of your class instead of same class object.